# How can I import a JS file with window object references in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a JS file `code.js` that will be loaded with a website containing code like the following:

```
window.someObject = window.someObject || {};

window.someObject.someFunction= function(aCondition) {
  if (aCondition) someExternalObject.someFunc2();
};

setTimeout(window.someObject.someFunction, 1000);
```

I can't change this code.

I want to write a unit test for this, so my test file would look something like this:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
var rewire = require('rewire');
var codeModule = require('./path/to/file/code.js');

describe('Test code.js', () => { //Using Mocha.js
 //Stub someObject.someFunction
 //Test stub with expect()
})
//MORE CODE
```

This results in `ReferenceError: window is not defined` since there is no window object in Node.

The reason I'd want to import that module is that I'd want to mock `someObject.someFunction` for my test.

**How can I deal with references to browser APIs like the window object when testing with Node?**
Do I need to require a package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/window) before?

I'm pretty new to this so bear with me if I have some misconceptions here.

Answer (score 0):

Before you import the file do this.

```
window = window || {}
```

It will define the `window` object in the global namespace, but of course with none of the good stuff you get in a browser.

Comment: I made two observations adding this to the test file:
1) The error remains if we use the pipe syntax. Instead of defaulting to the empty object the error gets thrown again.
2) If I simply use `window = {};` the reference error is carried over to `someExternalObject`. Generally speaking I would have to recreate every object that is referenced, but not created within `code.js` in my test file. This seems overly specific.